# Showing NginX welcome page after Dockerizing

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, next.js, dockerfile

I have Dockerized my Nextjs App. It builds fine. But after building, it keep showing the nginx welcome page, not the actual home page of my application. Tried many things, it doesn't fix. It remains the same on server too. What is the problem in my setup.
Here I am attaching my files.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.16.0 as builder

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY ./package.json /app/

RUN npm install

COPY . /app

RUN npm run build 

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

This is my Docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    container_name: kup-frontend
    image: kup-frontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/build
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
```

This is my nginx.conf file

```
server {
    listen 3000;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you expect to show your `nextjs`? Did you see https://www.koyeb.com/tutorials/how-to-dockerize-and-deploy-a-next-js-application-on-koyeb? Your `nginx.conf` file is working fine to show `nginx index` page.

Comment: I expect to show my next js apps home page instead of nginx index page. what to do?

Comment: If your site is 100% static (which it needs to be for you to be able to use nginx to serve it), you need to do `next export`. Does your build script to that? Normally export places the static site in a directory called 'out', but you copy from one called 'build'.

Comment: Did you see the link I told?